# c# Winforms how to size Form in class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So i made a class `public class Level : Form`,i want to make  a Level automatically without needing to make a form,to make it short everything and works except Size,
(I cant size the form),
in `Form_Load` i do `this.Size = new Size(1100, 700);`
And the form is something like (1, 1),

Comment: Here is screenshoot http://imgur.com/a/RUKxQ

Comment: Try setting ClientSize instead of Size

Comment: @JonathanWillcock still same

Comment: What are the AutoSize and AutoSizeMode properties of the Form? They should probably be false and/or GrowOnly, at a guess.

Comment: They are GrowOnly And AutoSize = false,but Still doesnt work

Comment: So here is screenshoot http://imgur.com/a/dE8Em

Comment: What is the form's default Minimum and Maximum size?, Set those to appropriate values. @VukUskokovic

Comment: How are you opening the Form?  I presume with Show()?

Comment: `private void Testlevel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Level Level1 = new Level();
            Level1.Show();
            Level1.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Close();
            this.Hide();
        }`
this is how i call the form

Comment: @SurajS TY YOU <3,thanks everybody it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MinimumSize Property

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(1100,700);
```